# An astronaut is standing on a ledge

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

An astronaut is standing on a ledge on the moon 5 meters above the ground, and falls off the ledge. How long will it take her to hit the ground? How fast will she hit the ground? Moon gravity is $1.622 \; m/s^2$.

Comment: Do you need to mention that Moon gravity is $1.622 m/s^{2}$? Also what is here mass/weight?

Comment: mass/weight is not given.

Comment: Gallilei: feather and lead fall with $g$.

Comment: @mvw, you are so correct, how did I forget this?

Comment: It is not obvious and amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the start time is $t_0=0$ and $x_0 = 5$ m, $v_0 = 0$ m/s, we have
$$
\ddot{x}(t) = -g \\
\dot{x}(t) - v_0 = -g t \\
x(t) - x_0  = -\frac{g}{2} t^2
$$
where we integrated twice and used the initial conditiond, and choose $t$ for $x(t) = 0$, which gives
$$
t = \sqrt{\frac{2x_0}{g}}
$$
Important is to use the Moon's gravitational acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this as integration, but I don't see the need. The kinematic equation of motion for constant acceleration is:

$$\Delta x = v_{x0}t + \frac12at^2$$

Defining the downwards direction as negative, we have $a = -g_{moon}=-1.622 \text{ m/s^2}$ and $\Delta x = -5 \text{ m}$. Also, given that the astronaut doesn't jump or throw herself down the ledge, the starting velocity is negligible: $v_{x0}=0$. Using these values, you can solve for $t$. From there can you solve for $v_x(t)$?